# A vaiable declared inside a function cant be accessed from a block that is in another function?

Tags: javascript, function, scope

So 'rand' is declared inside a function called 'makeMysteryFunc',
why when console.log(rand) will not print the numerical value that is randombly generated
but in stead just print it as console.log(rand).

Anybody can explain the scope here?

```js
hi question here
question about scoping
function makeMysteryFunc () {
    const rand = Math.random()
    console.log(rand);

    if (rand > 0.5) {
            return function () {
            console.log(rand);
            console.log(above 0.5)
    }

    } else {
            return function () {
            console.log(below 0.5)
    }
    }

}
why cant console.log(rand) be printed when it is declared inside a function ????
```

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors to make a runnable snippet that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the problem. Your example (after fixing syntax issues, see below), works properly for me.

```js
function makeMysteryFunc () {
    const rand = Math.random();
    console.log(rand);

    if (rand > 0.5) {
        return function () {
            console.log(rand);
            console.log("above 0.5");
        }
    } else {
        return function () {
            console.log(rand);
            console.log("below 0.5");
        }
    }
}

const f = makeMysteryFunc();
f();
```

Prints, for example,

```
0.5095959852493863
0.5095959852493863
above 0.5
```